# React-Native - Creating abstraction layer for AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to find a way to create an abstraction layer for using `AysncStorage` in react-native. I have tried to create a class with const methods but when I call it I get this error:

```
DOMNodes from htmlparser2 Array [
  Object {
    "data": "Error Hapened: TypeError: _reactNative.default.setItem is not a function",
    "next": null,
    "parent": null,
    "prev": null,
    "type": "text",
  },
```

This is the code for the js trying to access `AysncStorage`:

```
import AsyncStorage from 'react-native';

export const getClient = () => {
    return _retrieveData("loggedClient");
}
export const setClient = (client) => {
    _storeData("loggedClient", JSON.stringify(client));
}

export const clear = () => {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
}

_retrieveData = async (id) => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@App:"+id);
        if (value !== null) {
            // We have data!!
            console.log("found: " + id + "="+ value);
            return value;
        } else {
            console.log("Not found: " + id);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Failure retrieving "+ id +" error: " + error)
    }
};

_storeData = async (id, value) => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@App:'+id, value);
        console.log("saved");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Failure saving: " + error);
    }
};
```

any ideas on how I can create an Abstraction class in react-native to interact with `AsyncStorage`?

Comment: `_retrieveData` isn't returning `value`

Comment: Thank @DacreDenny, although this was not the root case of the problem the return was missing. I have adjusted the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the way you import `AysncStorage` to the following:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help 